# Create a url link with an ID for an action in Ionic 4/Angular

Tags: html, angular, ionic4

I am using Ionic 4/Angular. I want to send to the users an email with an embedded link to approve an action. Once they click the link, it will either redirect them to a webpage or back to a page on native app to show them they have approved the action. I will use the `ID` in the url to identify the user and store the `value="yes"` in FireBase. How could I achieve this? I could handle the database part but don't know how to create the url with an `ID` and also don't know how to pass the `ID` parameter back for further action.

There are similar topics in SO but nothing related to Ionic/Angular. I have googled and found the concept of "Ionic Deeplink" but not sure exactly if it could help to achieve my end or how to implement it. Hope someone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!

I also couldn't manage to make 'Deeplinks' work. However, I can redirect to a webpage and get the parameters (in this case, the 'id') by using getQueryParam().

the link: www.myapp.com/detail?id=1234

```
 import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

 constructor(private platform: Platform){
    console.log(this.platform.getQueryParam('id'));
 }

 // result: 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right Path

[Deeplinks plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks) and [Branch IO](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/branch-io) both offer what you're looking for, the process is as follows:

I personally had issues with Deeplinks and we ended up using Branch IO, here's [their documentation](https://docs.branch.io/resources/native-sdks-and-plugins/)

1. The endpoint in your API has a "base url" registered in the form needed for either of the 2 deeplink options and then appends the `Id` to it
2. You put that link in the email body and send it

When you configure your `Deeplinks` you tell the app to **register** "a domain" in the device, so instead of the regular `https://www.yourapp.com/home`, you can do something like `yourapp://home`, the device recognizes it has an application that can open that "kind" of link and prompts the user if he would like to go to the web version, or the native (app) version.

**UPDATE**

[Quick start on Branch IO](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking-attribution#configure-app)

app.component.ts

```js
initializeApp() {

  //Other initialization here

  Branch.initSession().then(data => {
    if (data['+clicked_branch_link']) {
      this.navCntrller.navigateRoot(data.$deeplink_path);
    }
  });
}
```

config.xml

```xml
<!-- sample config.xml -->
<widget id="com.eneff.branch.cordovatestbed" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <!-- Branch -->
  <plugin name="branch-cordova-sdk" spec="^3.1.6" />
  <branch-config>
    <branch-key value="key_live_ndqptlgXNE4LHqIahH1WIpbiyFlb62J3" />
    <uri-scheme value="branchcordova" />
    <link-domain value="cordova.app.link" />
    <ios-team-release value="PW4Q8885U7" />
  </branch-config>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation on the process. But do you have any coding examples on Deeplinks, especially where I can find the link and to be put in the email body? I think that will help me to understand more clearly. Thanks.

Comment: You have to create the link and associate it with your app, check the updated answer

Comment: Any examples on Deeplinks please instead of Branch IO?

Comment: I couldn't manage to make ```Deeplinks` work, It would open the app but it wont redirect me to the desired page, that's why I ended up using the other alternative